# OpenGL lighting: half of triangles not lit

Tags: opengl, lighting

I'm using the marching cubes algorithm described here `http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/` to turn a scalar field into a triangle mesh, and then displaying the mesh using OpenGL's GL_TRIANGLES mode. However, I'm having trouble with the lighting.

It seems like half the triangles are not being lit at all, and it's occurring in a distinct pattern.

In the program depicted below I've set the background to red, the front face color to green, and the back face color to blue. There is one light source with position (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0) and a sphere included for reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVZsM.png

And here it is with the triangles flipped, as in the drawing order of the last two vertices are switched:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJIb5.png  (back face color is blue)

Whats really confusing me is why the flipped version has color everywhere whereas the normal version doesn't. I figured that even if I drew stuff wrong, at least the flipped version should reflect the same error. Any idea what's happening?

Here is the complete lighting initialization code:

```
glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);

GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 50.0 };
GLfloat light_position[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

GLfloat mat_color1[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_color2[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_color1);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_color2);

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use the programmable pipeline?

Comment: Most probably your normals are bad.

Comment: Turns out normals were indeed causing the problem. A bug in my code was causing a lot of them to be set to the zero vector. How do I close the question?